# How to translate strings using xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

I have this piece of code:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//text()") as $q) {
    foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $q->nodeValue) as $line) {
        $str = trim($line);
        $translation = search_in_db_for_translation($str);
        if (!empty($translation) {
            replace string previously found by $translation
        }
    }
}
```

The script searches in an XML document for each string and if there is an available translation in the database (pairs {"input language string", "input language string"}) it must replace the string in the DOM document (after this translation there are more DOM manipulations). The problem is I'm unable to find a function to do this.

**EDIT**: In order to be clear, what I need is a way to modify the current line and only the current line ($line var or $q->nodeValue). Please see JWiley answer and my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as easy as:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//text()") as $q) {
    foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $q->nodeValue) as $line) {
        $str = trim($line);
        $translation = search_in_db_for_translation($str);
        if (!empty($translation) {
            $q->nodeValue = $translation;
        }
    }
}
```

It will replace the text and after this I just have to do a `$dom->saveHTMLFile($out)` in order to save the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `translate()` function in XPath:

```
translate(text(), "oldText", "replacementText")
```

Comment: Mhhh.. the problem with this solution is if I have a string ($line) like "Well" translated to "bueno" (spanish) and another one like "wellcome everybody" ("sed todos bienvenidos"). The 'translate' function will translate the second sentence to something like "buenocome everybody". Only text substitutions in the same $line that is edited are admisible. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question doesn't exactly state you wish to literally translate between languages though, that's different entirely. Good luck though